# influx DB: tokenize python list

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2

I have this query:

```
from(bucket: "my_bucket")
|> range(start: -24h)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "my_mea")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r.oper == "start")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] =~ /devices::.+::port_redir$/)
|> keep(columns: ["_value"])
```

That generates a single `_value` column like this where each row is basically a python list.

```
_value
[22, 161, 830, 57400]
[22, 161, 830, 57400]
[22, 161, 830]
[22, 161, 830]
[22, 161]
```

How can I tokenize the values in each row and add them into a new column?

```
new_col
22
161
830
57400
22
...
```